# В каком падеже написать?

Tags: морфология

В каком падеже (именительном или творительном) следует писать слова в скобках: «наряду с традиционными видами преступлений (хищения, преступления в сфере потребительского рынка) прослеживается...»?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вы заключили слова в скобки, они представляют собой вставную конструкцию, то есть не являются однородными членами предложения с обобщающим словом *видами*. Грамматика таких конструкций может быть совершенно самостоятельной, не зависеть от грамматики главного предложения. Каких-то специальных правил на этот счет я не нашла. Однако могу высказать собственное мнение. Вставная конструкция, использованная вами, не является самостоятельным предложением. Это лишь уточняющее перечисление. Поэтому я бы написала слова в скобках в творительном падеже. Для примера могу привести аналогичное предложение: *На некоторых мшарах (на Красном болоте и на болоте Пильном) уже началась добыча торфа* (Пауст.) (Из Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации под ред. Лопатина, § 97).

Answer (score 0):

Возможны оба варианта. И то, и другое является нормой.

Comment: А если это  вставная конструкция, то логичнее применит именительный падеж.

Comment: Не могли бы вы назвать источник, где говорится, что оба варианта нормативны? Ни у Лопатина, ни у Розенталя я не нашла разъяснений.